# How does PC/phone recognize person with one pic?

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

Recently, I'm studying about facial recognition with OpenCV, and I'm trying some simple example based on study.

I'm considering to use it at front door condition.

Nowadays some buildings or apartments use facial recognition for preventing intruders. When someone joins them (such as company or houses), they require the person's picture. As I know, they require just one picture.

I didn't care about that last time, but now, I'm very curious about it.
The famous algorithms such as PCA, LDA use machine learning, so they increase successful percentages(cases). To use machine learning, they need sample images as many as I can provide. That's why I'm curious about that. Buildings or companys require just one picture, but they can recognize each person. Moreover, their accuracy is very good. How can this happen? Is there any other algorithm besides PCA or LDA?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Of course there are tons of Algorithms that nobody wants you to know about because they are worth lots of money!

Comment: Study the paper facebook published on facial recognition that is "closely approaching human-level performance".

Comment: @Matt Haha, I also thought like that. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @William Oh, thanks for recommending. I'll read that paper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to read about facial recognition before, that time I wanted to do it as my semester project. And of course I have heard and thought of using OpenCV as well.

Your question is simple, those company or home that use facial recognition, they usually use very well-developed product, which normally includes well-programmed facial recognition. As we are talking about security here, normally companies will buy these security products, unless if they just want to use it as a tool to deter intruders which focus less on the practical usage, and recognition accuracy, they can opt for free facial recognition software.

So, when I'm talking about *well-programmed facial recognition*, it means that it was *trained* with huge amount of *databases* (the photos to be recognized that you mentioned), this means the *training* is done even *before* the software is officially launched, which is during the development stage. A good facial recognition software requires both good, complete and detailed programming coding, and also huge photo databases (taken at different ambient light intensity, different facial features like hair style, spectacles) to train it.

Therefore, the accuracy of the software does not depend solely on the amount of pictures given *during* the usage of the software provided that it is *well-programmed* in the first place. Thanks and hope I answered your question and wonder.

ps: recognize is spelled this way (US); recognise (UK)  =)

Comment: recognise is spelled this way in the UK! :)

Comment: you might want to change the word "recognize" in title

Comment: I personally sometimes confuse about the US and UK spelling. Even after several times looking at the lexicon..

Comment: Thanks for kind answers. I got what you mean. Even if I thought there are more things besides PICTURE, I feel it is sophisticating thing again.
PS. Ah, sorry for mistypings. Yes, I meant recognize.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this hasn't been achieved yet. So I don't think they can develop a software recognizing a person by using only one picture.
It is most likely that they teach the algorithm with the authorized person's pictures. So if that one picture does not match with the trained ones, the algorithm can say this is an intrusion.

**Edit:**

As linuxqwerty pointed out those commercial products are already trained with huge datasets.

As a result of this training, learning happens and the algorithm achieves feature extraction of all those sample faces.

Then the algorithm knows almost every kinds of features that an human face can have.

For example: thickness of eyebrows, distance between eyes, roundness of chin... These are only a human can say about faces. The algorithm can extract thousands of these features.

It can keep faces as a representation of those features.

So now we have this commercial software which can represent faces as binary codes with a lot of digits.

**I am getting your question again.**

The apartment or company bought this software.

They included the picture of authorized person.

What the software does is simply converting the picture as it was a thousand digits password.

So that person has this unique password which the system can only reproduce that password only from his face.

**To sum up:**

- The learning part was achieved using big face databases.
- Thanks to learning part, the recognition part can be done by using only one picture.

PS: Corrections are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for answer!. Well, if that is not recognizing, what can we call for that? Differentiating?

Comment: @Fatih: there are many algorithms used in commercial products for recognizing face with only one picture!

Comment: @TwilighT You're welcome. I will try to explain myself better by editing my answer.

Comment: @Derman Yes you are right. That is actually all what face recognition about. I think there is a misunderstanding on this question. I am editing my answer.

Comment: @Fatih: I mean there are products using just a single picture for training, not only for recognizing.

Comment: @Derman I've never encountered such thing before and can't think of how it can be achieved. It'd be nice if you can give some information or links about this.

Comment: As example, you can see border control systems in some European airports which will perform matching camera captured face with your passport photo or alike. Personally, I'm involving similar projects, so I can say with confidence that there are commercial technologies based on single image.

Comment: Even in your example, they have to train the algorithm somehow. Otherwise how can it know even it is a face or not. I am not even saying it can't recognize who is who. I am saying it cannot know what is a face look like and might confuse even with a chair or a desk.